# Notifications in php using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to implement a push notification in php, but i can´t have any value from there.

The code needs to increase the number of notifications when the expire_date is within a month to expire.

i have this for now:
php file fetch.php

```
    <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

    if(!$con){
        echo"Not connect to Server";
    }
    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'newusers')){
        echo 'Database not select';
    }
    $count=0;
    $DataAuditoria=_$POST['DataAuditoria'];
    $dateToday = date("Y-m-d");

    $query = "SELECT auditorias FROM Clientes";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $output = echo '';

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
    $DataAuditoria1=$row["auditorias"];
    if($DataAuditoria1 != "" && $DataAuditoria1 != NULL){
        $DataAuditoria_notificacao = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($DataAuditoria1)) . " -1 months"));

            $diasquefaltam= (int)((strtotime($DataAuditoria1) - strtotime($dateToday))/(60*60*24));

            if( $diasquefaltam<=30 && $diasquefaltam>=0){
                $output .= echo "{$row['Nome']}";
                $output.= echo "{$diasquefaltam}";
                $count++;

            }
}
}

else{
    $output .= echo "No Notifications for today";
}


$data = array(
   'notification' => $output,
   'unseen_notification'  => $count,
);

echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

html:
form to upload data

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="AuditoriaAdd" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-footer bg-3">
        <form role="form" method="post" id="comment_form" action="Teste_apagar.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="idClienteAuditoria" class="form-control" placeholder="" > 
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <h5>Enter Subject</h5>

            <input type="date" name="DataAuditoriaAdd" id="DataAuditoriaAdd" class="form-control">

        </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="post" id="post" class="btn btn-info" value="Post">Add</button>


  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

// updating the view with notifications using ajax

function load_unseen_notification(view = '')

{

 $.ajax({

  url:"fetch.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:{view:view},
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data)

  {

   $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);

   if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
   {
    $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);
   }

  }

 });

}

load_unseen_notification();

// submit form and get new records

$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 if($('#DataAuditoriaAdd').val() != '')

 {

  var form_data = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({

   url:"InsertBD.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   success:function(data)

   {

    $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
    load_unseen_notification();

   }

  });

 }

 else

 {
  alert("Both Fields are Required");
 }

});

// load new notifications

$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){

 $('.count').html('');

 load_unseen_notification('yes');

});

setInterval(function(){

 load_unseen_notification();;

}, 5000);

});
```

none of this seems to work, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the database query, you are selecting all the values in the table. Are you planning to truncate the table at different times of running this code? Else I would suggest that you add a datetime field or a key field for this specific request which you can compare and get the notifications.
- Your else is written in case no records are found in the table. You would need to change this as this would return a value only if your table is empty.
- In your jquery function, I can see the data being posted is in the `view` variable while in your php code, the post variable is `DataAuditoria`

Please correct these and let me know if the code works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working now. I follow your steps and its start to work. I have a new problem, i want that the notifications update by "itself" and not only if i create a new one (on click). Can you help me? I cant see what i can change in my script to do that.

Comment: You can add a cron job on your server which is like a scheduler. So you can run a job named updateNotifications every hour which checks if there are any new notifications. You can add the code to update notifications in that job. Please mark my answer as it has helped you solve your query.